# How to import TS from another "NPM-workspace'd" module

Tags: node.js, typescript, create-react-app, npm-workspaces

Why do I get a syntax error when I try to import typescript from a npm workspace module?

I have an app that I've created using 'create-react-app'. Its in a npm package called 'ui'. I wrote some helper functions as a part of that package, using TS. It all worked fine.

But as I am using npm workspaces, I thought I should move the helper functions into their own package. (So I can use them in the server package that I will write later etc)

So I:

- Created a new folder in `<my-root-package>/packages` - `utils`.
- Put a package.json in this new utils folder.
- Put the helper functions in `utils/index.ts`
- Ensured that `"./packages/common/utils"` is in the `"workspaces"` portion of the root package.json.
- Ran `npm i` from the root package to set up symlinks.

Finally, I put in a line of code in the `ui` package to import the fns from the `utils` package.

`import { fnUtils } from 'utils'`

But now I get this error when running my `ui` package:

```
ERROR in ../utils/src/fns/string/camelCase.ts 3:29

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:29)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ../../../node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Why is it not working anymore?

I wonder, is it because npm expects everything to be compilled into plain JS before its imported? If so, thats super annoying, I don't want to run any publishing or compillation while devving, hence using workspaces! What must I do to just import the utils directly as TS?

Its frustrating because I do have another project where I've managed to get this working. Unfortunately, I don't know how I did it!